# Algorithm to generate a random board in the game Unblock Me

Tags: algorithm

There's this popular game for the iphone called Unblock Me. The objective is to remove all the obstacles in front of the red block, to have a clear path to the exit:

[image]

What would be a sensible way to generate a random board for this game?
I am thinking something along these lines:

1. Place the red block at the exit.
2. Randomly place M blocks around the red block.
3. Make N random moves until the red block becomes blocked.
4. Increase M or N with each level.

Please note that mobile devices have limited CPU power and RAM, so efficiency is important.

Comment: You can generate random board outside the game and store the boards as levels in the game. No need to generate them within in the game. This keeps the levels consistent.

Comment: @nhahtdh, true, but I would like to create a genuinely unique experience for the user, where each level is completely different.

Comment: @Ramin: You should only do that when it is technically feasible. The search space for this problem might not make that possible if you also want to guarantee certain levels of difficulty.

Comment: What you are doing will make a level different for different user, even for different attempts.

Answer (score 2):

I've played that game a lot so here are some thoughts:

- Simply making *N* random moves doesn't necessarily make the level harder. You may end up in a state that can be solved in *n* moves where *n* is significantly smaller than *N*.
- The levels may be generated on a desktop machine and then simply included in the mobile game. This allows a far more exhaustive search (most likely tree-based and with backtracking) to make sure the level requires at least a certain number of moves to solve. The more difficult the level is supposed to be, the more moves should be required of course.
- You can add more knowledge into the algorithm: a vertical piece with length three has to be in the bottom position if you want the red piece to pass along. This limits the way the level can be solved. This can make the level more difficult, in particular when there are multiple vertical pieces in there.